# Gradle with Integrated SQL Security

Tags: sql-server, maven, gradle, build.gradle

I'm currently working on converting one of our Maven projects to use Gradle. 
Here is the issue I'm currently facing:

This project is using **SQL Integrated security**. Here is how Maven handles it (this took us a while to figure it out):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/sqljdbc4.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

after run `gradle init --type pom` 
this specific `dependency` has been converted to something like this:

```
system group: 'com.microsoft.jdbcdriver', name: 'sqljdbc', version:'4.0.1'
```

which is not right. Gradle can't build. More specifically, the `system` scope does not even exist in Gradle's API (neither I found it in any third party Gradle plugin).

Any help from whom had any experience with Gradle SQL integrated security would highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very easy to emulate scope `system` with Gradle by adding a configuration.

Create configuration `system` and set it as the compile classpath. Any dependencies added to `system` will now be available during compilation (though I doubt you need a specific JDBC driver for compilation), but the dependencies in `system` will not be added to the published dependencies of the module:

```
configurations {
    system.extendsFrom compile
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        compileClasspath = configurations.system
    }
}
```

Now you can easily add the JAR of the JDBC driver to the `system` configuration. This assumes you still want to refer to a local file just like with Maven:

```
dependencies {
    system files('libs/sqljdbc-4.0.1.jar')
}
```

But if you have the JAR in a (local) repository, it is better to use the repository:

```
dependencies {
    system 'com.microsoft.jdbcdriver:sqljdbc:4.0.1'
}
```